# how to use kedro.versioning in latest version of kedro?

Tags: kedro, cookiecutter

I have previously used kedro version 0.17.6 in my project. Now i have upgraded my version to 0.18.2. But in latest version of kedro there is no module of kedro.versioning. So i am getting a error that module is not found.